# Does there exist a square matrix $M$ such that $M M^\dagger =- M^\dagger M$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know there exist [normal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) such that  $M M^\dagger =  M^\dagger M$.(Note: $M^\dagger$ is the Hermitian conjugate of $M$)

I'm curious whether there exist a square matrix $M\neq0$ such that $M M^\dagger =- M^\dagger M$?

Comment: Of course, $M=0$ works

Comment: Hmm ... If $MM^\dagger$ and $M^\dagger M$ have the same dimensions, then $M$ must be a square matrix. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Certainly, nontrivil square matrix.

Comment: @HansEngler Yes, square matrix

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only such matrix is $M = 0$.

Note that if $MM^\dagger + M^\dagger M = 0$, then $x^\dagger [MM^\dagger + M^\dagger M]x = 0$ for all (column-vectors) $x \in \Bbb C^n$.  However,
$$
x^\dagger [MM^\dagger + M^\dagger M]x = 
(M^\dagger x)^\dagger(M^\dagger x) + (Mx)^\dagger (Mx) = 
\|M^\dagger x\|^2 + \|Mx\|^2
$$

Comment: (+1) Nice, clean answer! And I see you're almost in the 100k club, good luck with that ;)

Comment: Nice proof. Thanks.